# How many unique rows of pebbles are there?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

> A valid row of pebbles has $n$ white, and $n$ black pebbles. Thus, its
>   length is $2n$.
>
> Two rows of pebbles are considered *equivalent* if one can be produced
>   from another by any combination of inversions (replacing all whites with
>   blacks and vice versa) and flips (reverse the order of pebbles).
>
> How many *unique* rows of pebbles are there for some $n$?
>
> If we want our rows of pebbles to look *mixed*, we can say
>   that a *mixed* row of pebbles can't have more than $2$ consecutive
>   pebbles of the same color.
>
> (mixed case $m=1$ is trivial with only one solution per $n$)
>
> Then, how many rows of *unique mixed* pebbles are there for some
>   $n$? (mixed case $m=2$)

We can represent pebbles with $0$'s and $1$'s. 

I've tried generating examples for some $n$'s by iterating binary numbers;

We have solutions for first few $n$'s, for *unique* rows:

$$  1, 3, 7, 23, 71, 252, 890, 3299, 12283, 46508, \dots$$

**Edit:** Corrected thanks to [Jeremy Dover](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/342250/jeremy-dover) from comments: Now,  this sequence is in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A045723).

If we eliminate ones with $3$ or more same consecutive pebbles from previous examples;

Then we have the number of *unique mixed* ones for $n=1,\dots,10,\dots$ below ($m=2$):

$$ 1 ,3 ,5 ,12 ,25 ,61 ,140 ,347 ,841 ,2108 , \dots$$

**Edit:** Also corrected. This sequence still does not appear in OEIS.

> **Q:** How can we find these values for *unique mixed* examples algebraically?

*P.S. Is there any significantly faster way to generate all solutions for some $n$?* The outputs with all examples for the second sequence so far: [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/0h5jqgiE) ; Where second column is the decimal value and third is the difference between consecutive examples.

---

> *Also, would it be interesting to generalize this and find solutions for rows of size $k\times n$ where $k$ is the number of distinct
>   colors of pebbles, and also consider $m$ consecutive pebbles allowed?
>   
>  How does one calculate/compute a solution for some $(k,n,m)$?*

---

---

A follow up; If we were to have $2n$ rows of pebbles together to form a "pebble garden", how many *unique mixed pebble gardens* are there?

That is, now we also need to check the columns, as well as rows, for the same number of pebbles and for no three consecutive pebbles of same color. We also need to consider both horizontal and vertical flips and the 90° degree rotations for *uniqueness*, then this follow up is equivalent to the following question:

[How many distinct Unruly boards are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243967/how-many-distinct-unruly-boards-are-there)

P.S. *We could also stack the gardens into "pebble cubes", and continue to "pebble tesseracts", and continue to... $N$ dimensional unique pebble structures? But given the follow up has zero progress posed there as of this moment, this is perhaps still an overreach.*

Comment: For the first problem, your counts are incorrect. Looking at your pastebin for n=3, you have 100011 and 110001 counted as distinct, but they are isomorphic with respect to a flip. For n>=3, your counts seem to be off by exactly one each time. Using the corrected numbers, you can find your first sequence in the OEIS at http://oeis.org/A045723.

Comment: @JeremyDover That was a terribly missed error in my quick code. Thanks for noticing. I've corrected both sequences now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  starters   we  verify  the   formula  that  is  given   at  [OEIS
A045723](https://oeis.org/A045723)  which treats  the problem  without
adjacency  constraints. We  solve the  case  of $n$  instances of  $k$
colors for both $n\times k$ even and  odd. What we have here is a case
of **Power  Group Enumeration** with the  slot permutations consisting
of the identity  and the reflection. We represent the  color scheme by
by a  sequence of $k$ blocks  of $n$ identical colors,  $n\times k$ in
total. The object permutation group acting on these is obtained by the
simultaneous action  of the symmetric  group $S_k$ on the  $k$ blocks,
which encodes the fact that the  colors are swappable, and a vector of
$k$ permutations $\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_k$  from $S_n$ acting on the
constituents  of  the blocks,  which  encode  the  fact that  the  $n$
instances  of   the  $k$  colors   are  the  same.   Denote   this  by
$Z(F_{n,k}).$

For **Power Group Enumeration** we require the cycle index of the slot
permutation group which is

$$Z(Q_{n,k}) = \frac{1}{2} (a_1^{nk} + a_2^{nk/2})$$

when $n\times k$ is even and

$$Z(Q_{n,k}) = \frac{1}{2} (a_1^{nk} + a_1 a_2^{(nk-1)/2})$$

when $n\times  k$ is odd.   We must cover  these two with  cycles from
permutations from  $Z(F_{n,k})$ where we  are using a set  cover, i.e.
all colors  must be present.  Now  for the first one  there clearly is
only one possibility,  coverings using fixed points  from the identity
permutation.   Since   there  are  $k!\times  n!^k$   permutations  in
$Z(F_{n,k})$ we get a contribution of

$$\frac{(nk)!}{k! \times n!^k}.$$

The power of  $a_2$ requires more work and must  be simplified to make
for a  feasible computation.  Note  once more that  in a set  cover we
must use all cycles from the  permutation being sourced for the cover.
This clearly  requires for  the two permutations  to have  exactly the
same  cycle  structure.   Therefore we  are  extracting  $[a_2^{nk/2}]
Z(F_{n,k})$  and  $[a_1  a_2^{(nk-1)/2}] Z(F_{n,k}).$  Supposing  that
$\beta$  is the  permutation from  $S_k$  we see  that it  must be  an
involution, consisting of fixed points and two-cycles only, since this
is  the structure  of the  coefficient being  extracted and  we cannot
return to the  starting point of a cycle without  having made at least
one turn. Now  if $\beta$ fixes a certain block  then the contribution
from  that block  (permutation  $\gamma$) to  the  cycle index  enters
identically and hence it must be an involution as well.  One the other
hand if two blocks are on  a two-cycle the cycles where their elements
reside must have  even length wich implies they  are two-cycles.  This
means that  the corresponding  permutations $\gamma_a$  and $\gamma_b$
are inverses  of each other and  the joint action with  $\beta$ splits
everything into two-cycles. Using the exponential formula we introduce

$$Z(S_{q,\mid m}) = 
[w^q] \exp\left(\sum_{d|m} a_d \frac{w^d}{d}\right)$$

we thus obtain

$$[a_2^{nk/2}] Z(F_{n,k}) =
[a_2^{nk/2}] Z(S_{k,\mid 2})
\left(Z(S_{n,\mid 2}), \frac{1}{n!} a_2^n\right)$$

and similar  for $n\times k$  odd. Here  a cycle index  evaluated with
arguments signifies  substitution into $a_1,  a_2$ etc.  It remains to
observe that we have two choices  for each cycle being covered when we
cover the  two-cycles and  any permutation of  the source  cycles from
$Z(F_{n,k})$ is  valid.  We  finally get for  the desired  closed form
when $n\times k$ is even

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{(nk)!}{k! \times n!^k}
+ (nk/2)! \times 2^{nk/2} \times 
[a_2^{nk/2}] Z(S_{k,\mid 2})
\left(Z(S_{n,\mid 2}), \frac{a_2^n}{n!}\right) \right)}$$

and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{(nk)!}{k! \times n!^k}
+ ((nk-1)/2)! \times 2^{(nk-1)/2} \times 
[a_1 a_2^{(nk-1)/2}] Z(S_{k,\mid 2})
\left(Z(S_{n,\mid 2}), \frac{a_2^n}{n!}\right) \right)}$$

otherwise. We can compute these values with the following Maple code.

```
with(numtheory);
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


pet_cycleind_symm_nk_div2 :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local idx_col, idx_slot, res;

    if n=1 and k=1 then return a[1] fi;

    if n=1 or k=1 then
        return pet_cycleind_symm(n*k);
    fi;

    idx_col := coeftayl(exp(a[1]*z+a[2]/2*z^2), z=0, k);
    idx_slot := coeftayl(exp(a[1]*z+a[2]/2*z^2), z=0, n);

    res :=
    subs({a[1]=idx_slot, a[2]=a[2]^n/n!},
         idx_col);

    expand(res);
end;

EXA :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local idx;

    if n=1 or k=1 then return 1 fi;

    idx := pet_cycleind_symm_nk_div2(n, k);

    if type(n*k, even) then
        1/2*((n*k)!*coeff(idx, a[1], n*k) +
             ((n*k)/2)!*2^(n*k/2)*
             coeff(idx, a[2], n*k/2));
    else
        1/2*((n*k)!*coeff(idx, a[1], n*k) +
             ((n*k-1)/2)!*2^((n*k-1)/2)*
             coeff(coeff(idx, a[2], (n*k-1)/2), a[1], 1));
    fi;
end;

EXB :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local idx;

    if n=1 or k=1 then return 1 fi;

    idx := pet_cycleind_symm_nk_div2(n, k);

    if type(n*k, even) then
        1/2*((n*k)!/k!/n!^k +
             ((n*k)/2)!*2^(n*k/2)*
             coeff(idx, a[2], n*k/2));
    else
        1/2*((n*k)!/k!/n!^k +
             ((n*k-1)/2)!*2^((n*k-1)/2)*
             coeff(coeff(idx, a[2], (n*k-1)/2), a[1], 1));
    fi;
end;
```

We get for two swappable colors the sequence

$$1, 3, 7, 23, 71, 252, 890, 3299, 12283, 46508, 
\\ 176870, 677294, 2602198, \ldots $$

which matches  the data from  the OP.  With three swappable  colors we
find

$$1, 11, 148, 2955, 63231, 1430912, 33259920, 
\\ 788827215, 18989544145, 462583897776, \ldots $$

and with four the data are

$$1, 65, 7780, 1315825, 244448316, 48099214856, 
\\ 9844135755168, 2074189508907945, \ldots $$

The  initial segments  of these  may  be verified  with the  following
enumeration routine.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub recurse {
    my ($n, $k, $kf, $rest, $sofar, $orbits) = @_;

    if(scalar(@$sofar) == $n*$k){
        my $sofar_rev = [ reverse(@$sofar) ];

        my @orbit;

        for(my $idx = 0; $idx < $kf; $idx++){
            my @permcols = ( 0 .. ($k-1) );

            for(my ($d, $ind) = ($k, $idx); 
                $d > 1; $d--){
                my $pos = $ind % $d;

                if($pos != $d-1){
                    my $tmp = $permcols[$pos];
                    $permcols[$pos] = $permcols[$d-1];
                    $permcols[$d-1] = $tmp;
                }

                $ind = ($ind - $pos) / $d;
            }

            my $conf = join '',  map {
                chr(ord('A') + $permcols[$_])
            } @$sofar;

            push @orbit, $conf;

            $conf = join '',  map {
                chr(ord('A') + $permcols[$_])
            } @$sofar_rev;

            push @orbit, $conf;
        }

        my @sorted = sort(@orbit);
        $orbits->{$sorted[0]} = 1;
        return;
    }

    for(my $col = 0; $col < $k; $col++){
        if($rest->[$col] > 0){
            $rest->[$col]--;
            push @$sofar, $col;

            recurse($n, $k, $kf, $rest, $sofar, $orbits);

            pop @$sofar;
            $rest->[$col]++;
        }
    }
}

MAIN : {
    my $mx = shift || 5;
    my $k = shift || 2;

    my $kf = 1;
    for(my $f=2; $f <= $k; $f++){
        $kf *= $f;
    }

    $| = 1;

    for(my $n=1; $n <= $mx; $n++){
        my $orbits = {};

        recurse($n, $k, $kf, [($n) x $k],
                [], $orbits);

        print " " if $n > 1;
        print scalar(keys(%$orbits));
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

There  is   another  example   of  **PGE**   at  the   following  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594/).